# I am using unsplash-js api from NPM with react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using unsplash-js in my react project and when i am using search query for getting some random photos, I am getting return in form of JSON check below.

```
{total: 303, total_pages: 31, results: Array(10)}
```

*results
:
Array(10)
0
:
{id: "nitdfruLYys", created_at: "2016-10-12T13:04:23-04:00", updated_at: "2017-08-02T04:08:11-04:00", width: 4000, height: 6000, …}
1
:
{id: "XE87arvN3oo", created_at: "2015-12-12T11:43:35-05:00", updated_at: "2017-08-02T12:08:22-04:00", width: 4272, height: 2848, …}
2
:
{id: "iS0Aq3QPsJ4", created_at: "2016-02-26T19:51:15-05:00", updated_at: "2017-08-02T16:36:55-04:00", width: 3000, height: 1691, …}
3
:
{id: "41eXcLghVhI", created_at: "2017-07-15T20:50:43-04:00", updated_at: "2017-08-02T14:31:32-04:00", width: 4608, height: 3072, …}
4
:
{id: "EjlygRQAOik", created_at: "2017-02-07T19:59:18-05:00", updated_at: "2017-08-02T00:30:17-04:00", width: 5000, height: 3333, …}
5
:
{id: "WicMLrOSVvY", created_at: "2015-10-24T13:40:06-04:00", updated_at: "2017-07-31T07:00:30-04:00", width: 3456, height: 2304, …}
6
:
{id: "Fu8pblIzEL0", created_at: "2015-03-06T16:49:09-05:00", updated_at: "2017-08-01T20:41:35-04:00", width: 4928, height: 3264, …}
7
:
{id: "D9XX3Cjoh2s", created_at: "2016-02-21T15:45:25-05:00", updated_at: "2017-08-02T20:44:56-04:00", width: 6000, height: 4000, …}
8
:
{id: "Aka2x2D4Ph0", created_at: "2016-01-21T03:42:02-05:00", updated_at: "2017-07-28T10:24:12-04:00", width: 5616, height: 3744, …}
9
:
{id: "E-1tnSNP0y4", created_at: "2015-11-08T19:32:31-05:00", updated_at: "2017-07-30T17:19:06-04:00", width: 5472, height: 3648, …}
length
:
10
**proto**
:
Array(0)
total
:
303
total_pages
:
31
**proto**
:
Object*

I need to set this in a state as an array, but while i am setting this in my code i am getting this error: Objects are not valid as a React child

this.setState({ photos: json });

Comment: can you post a snippet of your relevant react code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9bhccn1y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try refactoring your code making use of the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { photos: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // make API calls here

        this.setState({ photos });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar />
                <PhotoList photos={this.state.photos} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

> I need to set this in a state as an array, but while i am setting this in my code i am getting this error: Objects are not valid as a React child

I think this is issue may be unrelated to the `setState` call.  This error occurs when the an object is passed to a react component as a child and would be called under the following cicumstance

```
render() {
    const sample = {
        a: 5,
        b: 6,
        c: 7
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {sample}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This being said, the error may be happening due to how you are using the photos within the `PhotoList` component.  I would check the usage of photos in the `PhotoList` and verify that `this.props.photos` isnt being passed as a child to a component.

Comment: Used your method but still showing the error -- Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, created_at, updated_at, width, height, color, likes, liked_by_user, description, user, current_user_collections, urls, categories, links})

Comment: `code`
componentDidMount() {
        // make API calls here
        unsplash.search.photos("dogs", 1)
        .then(toJson)
        .then(json => {
            //console.log(json.results);
            this.setState({ photos: json.results })
        }); 
    }

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: anytime bro, if you wanna hit that upvote button, i wouldnt be mad about it ;)